# How to format table and or chi-square for testing significance among categorical variables

Tags: r

I have this data set where I want to compare variables to see if any groups are significant by various categorical variables. When I use the following code, R returns an warning message saying the p-value may be wrong. Am I formatting the chi-square incorrectly?

```
df<-(group, gender, race, handedness
1, 0, 3, 0
1, 1, 3, 1
2, 1, 3, 0
2, 1, 3, 0
3, 0, 2, 1
3, 0, 2, 0)

# Is Gender significant among groups
gendertab<-table(df$gender, df$group)
chisq.test(gendertab)
# Is Race significant
racetab<-table(df$race, df$group)
chisq.test(racetab)
# Is Handedness significant
handtab<-table(df$handedness, df$group)
chisq.test(handtab)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try argument `simulate.p.value = TRUE` and compare the results to `fisher.test` ([R manual page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fisher.test.html) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)). They seem to agree with each other.

```
# Is Gender significant among groups
gendertab<-table(df$gender, df$group)
fisher.test(gendertab)
chisq.test(gendertab, simulate.p.value = TRUE)

# Is Race significant
racetab<-table(df$race, df$group)
fisher.test(racetab)
chisq.test(racetab, simulate.p.value = TRUE)

# Is Handedness significant
handtab<-table(df$handedness, df$group)
fisher.test(handtab)
chisq.test(handtab, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.csv(text = "
group, gender, race, handedness
     1, 0, 3, 0
     1, 1, 3, 1
     2, 1, 3, 0
     2, 1, 3, 0
     3, 0, 2, 1
     3, 0, 2, 0")
```